# comparing two text document for similarities in java

Tags: java, netbeans, string-matching

I've written code for comparing two text files. It is showing the result only if the match is in same position as in the first text file. I wanted to find match anywhere in other text file. Please suggest a way to do this. The code which i've written is shown below :

```
import java.io.*;

public class CompareTextFiles {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

      FileInputStream fstream1 = new FileInputStream("text1.txt");
      FileInputStream fstream2 = new FileInputStream("text2.txt");

      DataInputStream in1= new DataInputStream(fstream1);
      DataInputStream in2= new DataInputStream(fstream2);

      BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in1));
      BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in2));

      String strLine1, strLine2;


      while((strLine1 = br1.readLine()) != null && (strLine2 = br2.readLine()) != null){
          if(strLine1.equals(strLine2)){
              System.out.println(strLine1);

          }

      }

    }
}
```

Comment: Read both files into a string array or something. Do an O(n^2) operation to compare lines.

Comment: I would store only the first one in an array then read the second one. One this second loop, check the current line (use a counter to know on which line you are) and (OR ?) check if this line is in any other position which a contains method. This is a less memory used and one complete reading less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the whole content of one of the files to a string, rather than comparing line by line.

`String strLine1, strLine2;
     StringBuffer strFile2 = new StringBuffer(); 
     //Store the contents of File2 in strFile2
     while((strLine2 = br2.readLine()) != null) {
         strFile2.append(strLine2);
     }
     //Check whether each line of File1 is in File2
     while((strLine1 = br1.readLine()) != null){
         if(strFile2.toString().contains(strLine1)){
             System.out.println(strLine1);
         }
     }`

Comment: I would use a similar solution, using an array (collection) not a StringBuffer. If the file is too big, I would create some index table with the first caracter of each line and the position. Sort it to be able to search in it faster.